# offsetLeft returning 0 when parent repositioned

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an outer div `id='a'` and an inner div `id='b'`.

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">hey</div>
</div>
```

After I set the outer div position to `absolute` and reposition it, the inner div returns `0` for `offsetLeft`. But since setting `left ="30vw"` makes it farther from the left, I would expect it to be a larger number now, not `0`.

```js
const inner = document.getElementById("b");
const outer = document.getElementById("a");

console.log("offsetLeft of inner start: " + inner.offsetLeft);
// logging >> offsetLeft of inner start: 8

outer.style.position = "absolute";
outer.style.left = "30vw";

console.log("offsetLeft of inner: " + inner.offsetLeft);
// logging >> offsetLeft of inner: 0
```

How do I get the actual pixels from the left?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/dashbarkhuss/pen/wvjpJyo)

Comment: I think you may want to use getBoundingClientRect. refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) is relative to the HTMLElement object's `offsetParent`. The [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) of an element is its closest ancestor whose CSS `position` isn't `static`, or which creates a new [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Until `outer` has its `position` set, `inner`'s `offsetParent` is the `<body>` element, and so `inner`'s `offsetLeft` is relative to it:

```js
const inner = document.getElementById("b");
const outer = document.getElementById("a");

console.log("offsetParent of inner start: ", inner.offsetParent);

outer.style.position = "absolute";

console.log("offsetParent of inner: ", inner.offsetParent);
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">hey</div>
</div>
```

If you want to have the position relative to the viewport instead, then use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

```js
const inner = document.getElementById("b");
const outer = document.getElementById("a");

console.log("gBCR.left of inner start: " + inner.offsetLeft);
// logging >> offsetLeft of inner start: 8

outer.style.position = "absolute";
outer.style.left = "30vw";

console.log("gBCR.left of inner: " + inner.getBoundingClientRect().left);
// logging >> offsetLeft of inner: 0
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">hey</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding offsetParent's offsetLeft helped in calculation, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) "returns the number of pixels that the upper left corner of the current element is offset to the left within the HTMLElement.offsetParent node." So, if you move the `outer`, a change for the `inner` is not expected, since it is relative to the parent, in this case the `outer`.

To get the actual pixels from the left you can use the `offsetLeft` of the `outer`, like:

```
console.log("Actual pixels: " + outer.offsetLeft);
```